# Meaning of "concern" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the definition of *superficial* from OALD:

> not concerned with anything serious or important and lacking any depth of understanding or feeling

What does *concerned with* mean here? There are four senses of *concern* from OALD I find that all seems to be appropriate to the context:

> 1 [often passive] **concern somebody/something** to affect somebody/something; to involve somebody/something
>    - *Don't interfere in what doesn't concern you.*
>   - *The loss was a tragedy for all concerned (= all those affected by it).*
>   - *Where our children's education is concerned, no compromise is acceptable.*
>   - *The individuals concerned have some explaining to do.*
>   - *To whom it may concern … (= used for example, at the beginning of a public notice or of a job reference about somebody's character and ability)*
>   - *Everyone who was directly concerned in (= had some responsibility for) the incident has now resigned.*
>   - *Please pay attention because this information concerns all of you.*.
>
> 2 **concern something (also be concerned with something)** to be about something
>   - *The story concerns the prince's efforts to rescue Pamina.*
>   - *The book is primarily concerned with Soviet-American relations during the Cold War.*
>   - *This chapter concerns itself with the historical background.*
>   - *One major difference between these computers concerns the way in which they store information.*
>
> 3 worried and feeling concern about something
>   - *Concerned parents held a meeting.*
>   - **concerned about/for something** *The President is deeply concerned about this issue.*
>   - **concerned for something** *He didn't seem in the least concerned for her safety.*
>   - **concerned (that)…** *She was concerned that she might miss the turning and get lost.*
>
> 4 **concerned (about/with something)** interested in something
>   - *They were more concerned with how the other women had dressed than with what the speaker was saying.*

Comment: It's definition #2 - *superficial = not **relating to/about** anything important.*

Comment: It sounds like is definitely number 3. It is NOT number 1 in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original (and still core) sense of ***concern*** has its roots in Latin *con = with* and *cernĕre = to separate* (which also give us ***discern*** = distinguish, recognise with the *dis = apart* prefix).

That's to say, *concern = pertain to, be about, relate to* - effectively, OP's definition #2.

In fact, OP's initial definition *superficial = not [**concerned** with anything] serious or important* would seem perfectly adequate to me even with the [bracketed] portion removed entirely (it adds little extra meaning).

---

Outside of additional context, *"This problem concerns me"* could have several meanings, including...

> *it **affects** me* - I have some kind of relationship to the problem
>    *it's **about** me* - I am *central* to the problem (but I may not care much anyway)
>    *it's **important** to me* - I care a lot (but may not be personally involved)
>    *it **worries** me* - I care a lot, *and* have reason to fear the eventual outcome may not be what I want

I hope that series of definitions gives some idea of how the meaning has become "stretched" over time.

---

The sentence *"X is superficial"* (from French *superficiel = located at or on the surface*) normally means...

> *X is shallow, frivolous* - you won't find any "hidden depths" in X
>    *X is only interested in outward appearances* - X doesn't look for deeper meanings in anything

Thus although I said above that definition #2 applies for OP's purpose here, it's also possible to say that definitions #1 and #4 could apply...

> ***superficial***
>    1: *not **involving** anything important*
>    2: *not **about** anything important*
>    4: *not **interested in** anything important*

The one that hardly applies at all is #3. We wouldn't normally use *"John is superficial"* to mean *John isn't anxious about, or upset by, important things* (we'd say *unflappable, nonchalant, even-tempered*, etc.).